# Why ionic build and run command throws error?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

While running the below commands in my ionic app, i am getting the below error and not able to run the functions.

```
ionic cordova build --release android
ionic cordova run android


[13:31:27]  lint finished in 11.50 s
> cordova.cmd build android --release
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 14.0.1
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.
Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

The environment variable already has an entry
`JDK C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe –`

Comment: As you can see, JDK 1.8.x is required, whilst your PATH/JAVA_HOME points to a 14.x version.

Comment: The environment variable already has an entry JDK C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe

Comment: Yes it might have, but still it's a version 14.0.1. Cordova required JDK version 1.8, an older one than yours. Download the JDK 1.8 from here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html and make sure Cordova can find it under any of the given environment variables.

Comment: I do have jdk 8.0.2510.8 too. So how to update the environment variable setting?